# Como passar o que é executado em JS para campo input, na mesma página?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Preciso de uma ajuda que estou encravado aqui e, não entendo de AJAX. Tenho estes campos, select(tour), QTE(adults) QTE(Child) TOTAL ( onde executa o calculo). Preciso que ao calcular, ao clicar no icon, passe também para outro form, os valores: TOUR e o TOTAL calculado, tem como fazer isso, não queria enviar para outra página.

```
<td>
<div>
<select class="form-control" name="tour" id="tour">
<option>Choose a tour</option>
<option value="98">Douro Valley Tour</option>
<option value="118">Bairrada Wine Tour</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="numbers-row">
<input type="text" value="1" id="adults" class="qty2 form-control" name="adults">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="numbers-row">
<input type="text" value="0" id="child" class="qty2 form-control" name="child">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<span id="soma"></span>
</td>
<td class="options">
<a href='javascript:calcular();'><i class="icon-ccw-2"></i></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function calcular() {
        var unit = "45";
        var tour = Number(document.getElementById("tour").value);
        var adults = Number(document.getElementById("adults").value);
        var child = Number(document.getElementById("child").value);
        var elemResult = document.getElementById("soma");

        if (elemResult.textContent === undefined) {

        elemResult.textContent = String(tour * adults + unit * child)+ ".00€";
        }
        else { // IE
        elemResult.innerText = String(tour * adults + unit * child) + ".00€";
            }
        }
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="SELECT">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="TOTAL">
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que quer dizer com "passar para outro form".

Comment: Apenas quero passar o valor do select e o campo ID onde mostra o Total, para os campos abaixo...ios dois inputs em baixo.

Comment: Comece colocando um id nesses campos. Depois você pode atribuir valor com `document.getElementById('id-do-input').value = 'valor desejado';`.

Comment: O meu JS e muito mau: o 'valor desejado' para passar o valor do select qual seria?

Comment: Você que me diga. Não seriam os valores que você já tem na variável `tour`, em um dos inputs, e o resultado da sua conta no outro?

Comment: sim, mas ai so me passa tipo .value='tour' ---- tour

Comment: REsolvido...obrigado amigo

Answer (score 0):

Seta o innerText ou innerHTML do resultado que você teve para onde você quer que ele apareça.

Ex: `const resultado = document.querySelector('.resultado-achado').innerHTML;`

No campo, texto ou outro form seria: `document.querySelector('.outro-texto').innerHTML = resultado`

Comment: pode me mostrar um exemplo cesar???

Comment: Eu postei o exemplo na minha resposta. O seu input precisa ter um id ou classe, e aí onde eu coloquei no exemplo como .resultado-achado, você coloca o nome do seu input. Pra entender precisa entender 1 pouco de javascript.

Comment: ja resolvi, muito obrigado pela ajuda.